# Problem using the quantile function (inverse CDF) of a standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

What does this equation mean for a random variable $Z\sim\text{N}(0,1)$?
How am I supposed to find $z_0$?
$$\text{Prob}(|Z|>z_0)=0.01$$

Comment: Do you have a table to look up the values?

Comment: Assuming $z_0$ is positive, then $|Z| > z_0$ if and only if $Z < -z_0$ or $Z > z_0$.  So the 0.01 would be the total of the area underneath the curve to the right of $z_0$ and to the left of $-z_0$.  It depends on your table, but you would probably look up 0.01/2 = 0.005 in the body of the table to find $z_0$

Comment: I'm supposed to use the R statement qnorm to find it.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In R, `qnorm(1-.01/2)` returns 2.575829. And to check,
`1 - diff(pnorm(c(-2.575829, 2.575829)))` returns 0.01000001.

Furthermore, the following simulation is relevant for verification (slightly different result on each run; expect about three-place
accuracy).

```
z = rnorm(10^6);  mean(abs(z) > 2.575829)
## 0.010025
```

Again:

```
z = rnorm(10^6);  mean(abs(z) > 2.575829)
## 0.009934
```

For the last two parts, verifying the first resiult, you may need to check out `diff`, `rnorm`, and also taking a `mean` of a logical
vector.

If you don't understand any part of this, please leave a Comment
and I'll check back in a couple of hours.